# Align woocommerce price when title is bigger or smaller

Tags: html, css, woocommerce, alignment

[image: WooCommerce Divs]

I need to align the price of the products and make them (if possible) relative to the button instead of the title above them. I also want to avoid min-height if it's possible. Any suggestions?

Comment: You can position both the button and the price relative to the bottom of the container.

Comment: Can you post some code? Your relevant html and css at least.

Comment: @Gerard can you explain please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.product-container {
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
  width: 250px;
  height: 470px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: thin solid #999;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
.product-description {
  width: 100%;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: .8em;
  padding: 10px 0px;
}
.product-price {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 50px;
  padding-top: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.add-to-cart {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 15px;
}
button {
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: orange;
  color: white;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5%;
}
```

```html
<div class="product-container">
  <div class="product-image"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x350"></div>
  <div class="product-description">American crew powder cleanser style remover shampoo 250ml</div>
  <div class="product-price">€19.95</div>
  <div class="add-to-cart">
    <button>Add to cart</button>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="product-container">
  <div class="product-image"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x350"></div>
  <div class="product-description">American crew pomade 85ml</div>
  <div class="product-price">€12.15</div>
  <div class="add-to-cart">
    <button>Add to cart</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have created an example. I can't see your code so I had to make a few assumptions. Let me know if this works for you.
Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/beekvang/q30odku9/1/

Comment: Thank you it helps a lot. The only thing is that it shouldn't be there is to 
 the fixed height and width because it would break the whole site on smaller screens...

Comment: I understand. Just keep in place for the container what you have now. I had to use fixed width and height because of the limited size of the window. Otherwise it wouldn't fit.

Comment: It does its job perfectly. Thank you!